# How can i fix the "clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'" problem in VisualStudioCode on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, clang, clang++

Hey i tried to start with c++, but i have a problem. I use VisualStudio Code on Mac but there is a fopnemp problem.

clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

> Executing task: make build_single --file=/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/.vscode/Makefile --directory=/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/1_Intro/ FILE_NAME=/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/1_Intro/main.cc COMPILATION_MODE=Debug CPP_COMPILER=clang++ EXECUTABLE_NAME=mainDebug

> clang++ -g -std=c++17  -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o mainDebug "/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/1_Intro/main.cc"
> clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
> clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
> make: *** [build_single] Error 1
> The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'make build_single --file=/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/.vscode/Makefile --directory=/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/1_Intro/ FILE_NAME=/Users/benediktlennartbeste/Desktop/CppKurs1/1_Intro/main.cc COMPILATION_MODE=Debug CPP_COMPILER=clang++ EXECUTABLE_NAME=mainDebug'" failed to launch (exit code: 2).<

<

Comment: `-Xclang -fopenmp` and `-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp` work fine in Apple clang.